# Getting value of enclosed inputs with cells of a table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `td` like this:

`<td>
<input type="text"id="Collection" name="Collection" value="***">
</td>`

I want to access the `***` values to export the table with this jquery code to XML:

```
$("#AdExportXML").click(function () {
    var xml = "<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<Questions>\n";
        $("#Questions tr").each(function () {
            var cells = $("td", this);
            if (cells.length > 0) {
                xml += "    <Question>\n";
                xml += "      <Collection>" + cells.eq(2).html() + "</Collection>\n";
                xml += "    </Question>\n";
            }
        });
        xml += "\n</Questions>\n";

    console.log(xml);
    var blob = new Blob([xml], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, Date.now()+".xml");

});
```

Now, the given value is the entire html:

`<input type="text"id="Collection" name="Collection" value="***">`

How can I access its value especially?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `find()`/`children()` and `val()` methods?

Comment: The `val()` method returns an `object` and it\`s not a processable value; Also
I`m not familiar with the other one.

Comment: `val()` on a jQuery object containing an element that has a value property, returns the value of the element.  https://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: Then I should use `val()` after `cells.eq(2)` to get an object; Then How can I proccess on it?

Comment: `cells.eq(2)` gets you the td, not the input.  Thus the need to use find() or children() to get the input first, before using val() on it.  Please reference these methods in the api for more information.

Comment: Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/  is also a pretty hand website for developers stating out in jQuery and want to learn more, and find the api to be less than friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Taplar pointed out... the cells.eq(2) is referencing to the td. 
You need to now refer to the input field inside the td.

```
xml += "      <Collection>" + cells.eq(2).find('input').val() + "</Collection>\n";
```